# C# Compile in memory and create instance of memory assembly types

Tags: c#, compilation, activator

How can I Load an assembly to memory and instatiate one of its types by using their name?

I have this to compile:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Compiles the input string and saves it in memory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="referencedAssemblies"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static CompilerResults LoadScriptsToMemory(string source, List<string> referencedAssemblies)
    {
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

        parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = false;

        //Add the required assemblies
        foreach (string reference in referencedAssemblies)
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(reference);

        foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            if (asm.Location.Contains("Microsoft.Xna") || asm.Location.Contains("Gibbo.Library") 
                || asm.Location.Contains("System"))
            {
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(asm.Location);
            }
        }

        return Compile(parameters, source);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compiles a source file with the given parameters and source
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parms"></param>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static CompilerResults Compile(CompilerParameters parameters, string source)
    {
        CodeDomProvider compiler = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        return compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
    }
```

Then, I try to use this to instantiate on of the members generated in memory by the code above:

```
    var handler = Activator.CreateInstance(SceneManager.ScriptsAssembly.FullName, name);
    ObjectComponent oc = (ObjectComponent)handler.Unwrap();
```

SceneManager.ScriptsAssembly.FullName :> I save the compiled assembly in SceneManager.ScriptsAssembly.

name :> name of the type I want to load

I got this error:

> Error loading scene: Could not load file or assembly 'nhvneezw, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The assembly name is correct. What may it be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The left the important code out.  Don't forget to check CompilerResults.Errors.  If you save the assembly then don't compile to memory.  Use Fuslogvw.exe for tough cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerresults.compiledassembly.aspx)

> The get accessor for the CompiledAssembly property calls the Load method to load the compiled assembly into the current application domain

You can use Assembly.CreateInstance(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dex1ss7c.aspx) method instead of Activator. If you need to create instance only by type name, you have to get value of CompilerResults.CompiledAssembly property.

Comment: Thanks!

I was able to load them correctly with the Assembly.CreateInstance()

;)